# Не выводится информация при подгрузке файлов AJAX'ом в Опере, Яндекс браузере, Эксплорере и Эдже

Tags: javascript, ajax, opera

Делаю Онлайн-Консультант для чата. Сообщения у пользователя каждые 2 секунды подгружаются через AJAX (не надо мне кричать, что так уже не делают, я знаю). Так вот, использую скрипт:

```
function show() {  
    $.ajax({  
        url: "<?bloginfo('template_url');?>/load_messes.php",  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
            $("#result_div_id").html(html); 
            $i++;
        }  
    });  
}  

$(document).ready(function(){  
    show();  
    setInterval('show()',2000);  
});
```

Сайт у меня стоит на вп. Кода отправляю сообщение, идет по-сути, тот же скрипт, только там идет подгрузка другого файла - form.php. В него передается сообщение пользователя и оно дабавляется в бд. А вот вывод load-messes.php почему-то работает только в Хроме. Заранее спасибо)